# jQuery: Using .after() or .before() adds element to last item in selection only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using jQuery for a while but this is a new one. A simplified example:

HTML

```
<div class='custom'></div>
<div class='custom'></div>
<div class='custom'></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $customElems = $('.custom'),
    $spanOuter   = $('<span class="outer"/>'),
    $spanInner   = $('<span class="inner"/>');

$customElems.each( function() {
    $(this).wrap($spanOuter).after($spanInner);
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a3ZK8/

I would have expected the 'inner' span to be added to all three elements in the selection but it gets always inserted into the last one only (no matter how many). I tried it with .before(), with and without the chaining, same result. What am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone the element.  Otherwise, `after()` will relocate the same element 3 times, which  results in it being attached to only the last looped element.

```
$customElems.each(function () {
    $(this).wrap($spanOuter).after($spanInner.clone());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d57V3/)

You might ask, "Why would `wrap()` work?" That's because 'wrap()' internally [clones the element](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/wrap.js#L20).

Comment: Thanks! Answer accepted as the first responder, however
François' and Kevin's answers are also enlightening.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are using a **reference** to a jQuery object.

Hence you keep moving the object **reference** around within each iteration.

If you have no events attached or no need for the `span` to be a jQuery object then just pass the parameter as a HTML string literal instead of an object **reference**

Cloning a jQuery object that doesn't need to be a jQuery object in the first place is just redundant processing and unnecessary overhead.

Change your jQuery object to a string similar to this:

```
spanInnerString  = '<span class="inner"/>';
```

and your method like this:

```
$(this).wrap($spanOuter).after(spanInner);
```

The result is:

```
<span class="outer"><div class="custom"></div><span class="inner"></span></span>
<span class="outer"><div class="custom"></div><span class="inner"></span></span>
<span class="outer"><div class="custom"></div><span class="inner"></span></span>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eT32r/) - Passing parameter as HTML string

---

Off course, the same goes for the outer span. Don't create jQuery objects unless you have to.

If you must use a jQuery object because you want to attach events to the `span` or similar, than cloning is the way to go, though make sure you use `clone(true, true)` then to also clone the attached events.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out the unnecessary jQuery object creation! Picked it up from a tutorial somewhere; it did seem a bit strange.

Answer (score 2):

You're moving the same span from place to place. If you acted on all three divs at once, jquery will instead clone the span.

http://jsfiddle.net/a3ZK8/1/

```
var $customElems = $('.custom'),
    $spanOuter = $('<span class="outer"/>'),
    $spanInner = $('<span class="inner"/>');

$customElems.wrap($spanOuter).after($spanInner);
```

From the documentation for .after:

> **Important:** If there is more than one target element, cloned
>   copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except
>   for the last one.

which means the last element will always get the original, while all other selected elements will get a clone. That's why when you acted on one element at a time, it simply moved the same span around.

Comment: Well, awesome. Ha, I would've interpreted the documentation to mean quite the opposite! Another interesting tidbit from your answer is understanding the exact difference between .each() on a selection vs not using it -- seems the desired operation gets applied to all elements in both cases, albeit in different ways?

Comment: Correct. When you use .each, the operation is performed on each element as if you only selected that one element, where as when you perform it on them all at once it performs as if you're working on them all at once.